# How do I open or smash these silver blocks and padlocks?

Tags: lego-lord-of-the-rings

Having reached the end of the game's storyline, we're now freeplaying around Middle Earth, picking up collectables, etc. The silver blocks and padlocks (as modelled below by Frodo) are getting in the way, as we don't seem to have a character available that can deal with them (or, we do and I've failed to notice).

Presumably, there is a character and/or a craftable tool that can do the job.
**So which characters or tools can I use to break silver objects, and how do I obtain them?**

[image: cropped screenshot of LEGO LOTR showing silver padlocks]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order of first available in terms of game process, the following can be used to destroy these blocks:

#### Berserker Orc character

Purchased at a cost of 200000 studs.

Becomes available after completing the story level *Helm's Deep*

The character can be found on the world map, near Helm's Deep.
You can find him behind the Deeping Wall.

#### Mithril Fireworks item

Forged with a cost of 16 Mithril blocks.

Plan becomes available after the storyline level *The Black Gate*.

The plan can be found on the world map, near Barad-dúr (Sauron's Tower).
It's located above the door of the gate on the east side.

Comment: Berserker is also strong and therefore able to pull orange handles.

Comment: I'd like to add that there are a few blocks/cave entrances that can only be opened by the Berserker and not by the Fireworks, so if you want to be able to open all silver blockades, then you'll need the Berserker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bezerker to destroy silver lego. You can also craft mithril fireworks for 16 mithril bricks to destroy silver lego. In the weapons DLC pack there is an exploding cake which has the same affect.

Comment: Where do I find the bezerker?

Answer (score 0):

***NYEHEHE!***

The Mithril Fireworks or Berserker Orc will be of help!

Complete the Helm's Deep Mission and then use Sam's rope to get over the Deeping wall then climb the stairs on the right side and you will find him. Be sure to have 200,000 studs because he is quite expensive!

The recipe for the Mithril Fireworks are in Barad Dur at the back of the tower. You will need an Elf or someone else who can jump high because you have to climb onto a little plank! Gothmog is there too so you can buy him while you are at it! It will cost 16 Mithril bricks to forge it.

Alas the Great Papyrus must go now to another Human in need of Amazing help!

Comment: This doesn't add anything new to a 5 year old question. Both Mithril Fireworks and Berserker Orc were mentioned in the accepted answer

Comment: Well atleast i said where they are at...